# Stub python time method with mockito (when)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mockito, stub

In the code, I'm using the python method `time()`:

```
from time import time

# Some code
t=time()
# Some more code
```

*main.py*

In my tests, I want to stub the time method with mockito, to return always the same value:

```
import time
#...
when(time).time().thenReturn(2)
#...
```

*test.py*

However, that doesn't work unless I change how I call the time method in main:

```
import time
t=time.time()
```

*main_2.py*

I would like to avoid changing the main code, or at least understand why that change is needed in order for the stub to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong module. Your code is using the name `time` in its *own* namespace, not the name in the `time` module, although both refer to the same function.

If `test.py` is importing `main.py` with `import main`, then use

```
when(main).time().thenReturn(2)
```